# Specify route rules, and route to different components

Tags: mason, poet

I know how to to specify routes for page components using [Mason::Plugin::RouterSimple](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-Plugin-RouterSimple-0.07/lib/Mason/Plugin/RouterSimple.pm), for example given a url of:

```
/archives/2015/07
```

I can create a component `archives.mc` as this:

```
<%class>
  route "{year:[0-9]{4}}/{month:[0-9]{2}}";
</%class>
Archives for the month of <% $.month %>/<% $.year %>
```

and similarly I can create a `news.mc` component that will handle urls of:

```
/news/2012/04
```

and that's fine (and very elegant!) but now what I want is to be able to handle urls like the following ones:

```
/john/archives/2014/12
/john/news/2014/03
/peter/news/2015/09
/bill/archives/2012/06
```

etc. I know I can write the route rules as:

```
<%class>
  route "{user:[a-z]+}/archives/{year:[0-9]{4}}/{month:[0-9]{2}}", { action=> 'archives' };
  route "{user:[a-z]+}/news/{year:[0-9]{4}}/{month:[0-9]{2}}", { action=> 'news' };
</%class>
```

but then the requests have to be handled by two different components. How can I route a request to different components? `archives.mc` and `news.mc` won't be matched by Mason because there's a username before the name of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, while urs like `/archives/2014/12` can be easily handled by an `/archives.mc` component, for urls like `/john/archives/2014/12` and `/bill/archives/2012/06` it's not clear where to put the archives component.

Mason will try to match the following components (it's a simplified list, please see [Mason::Manual::RequestDispatch](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-2.24/lib/Mason/Manual/RequestDispatch.pod)):

```
...
/john/archives.{mp,mc}
/john/dhandler.{mp,mc}
/john.{mp,mc}
```

but finally...

```
/dhandler.{mp,mc}
```

So my idea is to put a `dhandler.mc` component in the root directory:

```
<%class>
  route "{user:[a-z]+}/archives/{year:[0-9]{4}}/{month:[0-9]{2}}", { action=> 'archives' };
  route "{user:[a-z]+}/news/{year:[0-9]{4}}/{month:[0-9]{2}}", { action=> 'news' };
</%class>
<%init>
  $m->comp($.action.'.mi', user=>$.user, year=>$.year, month=>$.month);
</%init>
```

If the url matches the first route, it will call the `archives.mi` component:

```
<%class>
  has 'user';
  has 'year';
  has 'month';
</%class>
<% $.user %>'s archives for the month of <% $.month %>/<% $.year %>
```

(I used a `.mi` component so it will be accessible only internally).

The dhandler can be improved (better regexp, can check users from a database table and deny the request, etc.)

Since my archives and news components can accept POST/GET data, and since I want to accept any data, I can just pass everything with:

```
 $m->comp($._action.'.mi', %{$.args});
```

Not too elegand, but it looks like it does its work.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier (and cleaner) switch the "application logic" from `/user/action/...` to `/action/user`? (in such case you will match both `/archives.mc` and `/news.mc`.) This can be done using some rewrite middleware, e.g. before the URL's reach Mason.

Comment: @jm666 yes, switching from `/user/action/...` to `/action/user/...` would be easier and cleaner. But on this particular context I really need to have the user first, for url consistency ... I was thinking on rewrite urls before they reach Mason but I didn't know where to start :)